# Cinamon: Уведомления поверх ВСЕХ окон

Tags: linux, уведомления, push-уведомления

Доброго времени суток.

У меня стоит система Linux Mint 18 (Cinamon). Перешел с Ubuntu и Mint (Mate).

Столкнулся с проблемой, что уведомления на рабочем столе не показываются при воспроизведении полноэкранного видео и работе fullscreen приложений. Это является большой проблемой, так как, работая на ноутбуке, можно проглядеть уведомление о критически низком заряде батареи. Стоит отметить, что в Unity, Gnome2 и Mate подобного поведения замечено не было (уведомления отображались даже поверх игр).

Подскажите возможные решения данной проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

[Проблему](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/1646) [исправили](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/pull/6459) в апреле 2017 года, но для Mint 18 обновления нужных пакетов, как я понимаю, нет.

Можно обновиться до Mint 18.3.

Можно дождаться выхода Mint 19, и перейти на него.

Можно добавить репозиторий со свежими сборками cinnamon и обновиться:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Обновил пакеты, но уведомления так и не показываются поверх видео...

Comment: Должны показываться только критичные уведомления. Они тоже не показываются?

Comment: Критические проверить пока не было возможности. Как сделать, что бы отображались все?

Comment: +50 за попытку помочь дал, но проблема так и не решена...

Comment: Проверить critical можно так:

sleep 5; notify-send -u critical test

Comment: Проверил в свежем cinnamon на ArchLinux, проблема правда не решена.

Comment: Странно как-то, вроде работает, но через раз. Чего-то намудрили они там, по коду не очевидно :-(.

Comment: Так точно, критические показывает... Но нужно, что бы показывало все...

Comment: Всё равно не показывает разряд...